# Is there a matrix with real entries such that $A \ne I_2$ but $A^3 = I_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Is there a matrix with real entries such that $A \ne I_2$ but $A^3 = I_2$.

I've actually encountered with this post:

[$A$ a $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that $A^3 = I$ but $A \ne I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/835715/160028)

Although it present a $3\times 3$ matrix, I can guess there's an equivalent for $2\times 2$. Anyhow, I don't quite understand what process should be made in order to find such matrix.

I did find that $\lambda=1$ is eigenvalue of $A$

Comment: Why is 1 an eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: do you know Rotation matrix?

Comment: for $A \neq I ,A^3=I_2$ this is a answer$$r_{\alpha }=\begin{bmatrix}
cos \alpha  & -sin\alpha\\  
 sin \alpha &  cos \alpha
\end{bmatrix}\\(r_{\alpha })^n=r_{n\alpha }\\A^3=I_2\\A=r_{\frac{2\pi }{3}}\rightarrow  A^3=r_{\frac{2\pi }{3}}^3 =r_{3\frac{2\pi }{3}}=r_{2\pi}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Example**
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(120^\circ) & \sin(120^\circ) \\
-\sin(120^\circ) & \cos(120^\circ) \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, if $P$ is any invertible matrix, then $PAP^{-1}$ also has this property, with the above $A$.

If you know about complex eigenvalues/eigenvectors, you can prove that any matrix with this property must have non-real eigenvalues [as the only possible real eigenvalue is 1, and neither the diagonal nor the Jordan Canonical form with $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$ can satisfy this relation], and then that it must have this form.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, consider
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos2\pi/3 &\sin2\pi/3\\
-\sin2\pi/3& \cos2\pi/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Minor modification gives an example for any other natural $k\geq2$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is a standard embedding homomorphism from the field of complex numbers to ring of real $2\times 2$ matrices:

$$a+bi \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$$

So find a complex cube root of $1$.

There are actually cases with entries rational. For example:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-1}{2}&\frac{-3}{4}\\1&\frac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

In general, you want a matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $x^2+x+1$. Then $A^3-I=(A-I)(A^2+A+I)=0$.

$$\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda +(ad-bc)$$

So you wan $a+d=-1$ and $ad-bc=1$, or $d=-(a+1)$ and $bc=ad-1=-(a^2+a+1)$. This means you can take any value $a$ and get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&1+a+a^2\\-1&-(a+1)\end{pmatrix}$$

Which means you can get an all-integer solution, in particular.

Comment: Your second matrix is not of the form you suggested in the first place.

Comment: I never said the first form was the only form - I clearly indicated with "So find.." That there was more to do. Then I moved on to other examples.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: Why would I want the characteristic polynomial to be $x^2+x+1$?

Answer (score 4):

You just have to take the companion matrix of $\Phi_3(x)$, i.e. the third cyclotomic polinomial:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$
We have $A,A^2\neq I$, but $A^3=I$.

Comment: We had the same mind, apparently.

Comment: This solution is a conjugate of the rotation solution ;)

Comment: @johannesvalks: obviously, since the roots of $\Phi_3$ are the primitive third roots of unity.

Answer (score 2):

You can even demand that $A$ have integer entries.  For example,
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Comment: This solution is a conjugate of the rotation solution ;)

Comment: Of course, it is.  Every solution to $A^3=I$, except the identity, is conjugate to the $3$-fold rotation matrix.  That is not the point of my reply.

Answer (score 2):

Given

> $$
> \mathbf{A}_n^3 = \mathbf{I}_n
> \hspace{1em} \textrm{and} \hspace{1em}
> \mathbf{A}_n \ne \mathbf{I}_n. \tag {OP}
> $$

## Eigenvalues

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}_n$.
Therefore
$$
\mathbf{A}_n \vec{x}_\lambda = \lambda \vec{x}_\lambda.
$$
Whence
$$
\mathbf{A}_n^k \vec{x}_\lambda = \lambda^k \vec{x}_\lambda.
$$
From (OP) follows
$$
\lambda^3 = 1.
$$

---

It is also clear that
$$
\lambda^3 = 1 \Longrightarrow \big( \lambda^k \big)^3 = 1.
$$
Therefore we obtain

> $$
> \lambda \ne 1,
> p + q > 0,
> p+q+r = n :
> \mathbf{A}^\flat_n =
> \left[
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> \lambda \mathbf{I}_p & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & \lambda^2 \mathbf{I}_q & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & \mathbf{I}_r
> \end{array}
> \right]. \tag {A1}
> $$

## Property of eigenvalues

Let us define
$$
z = 1 + \lambda + \lambda^2.
$$
We have
$$
\lambda z = z \Rightarrow \big( \lambda - 1 \big) z = 0 \Rightarrow
\lambda = 1 \vee z = 0.
$$
As $\lambda = 1$ excludes (OP), we have $z=0$, thus

> $$
> \lambda + \lambda^2 = -1. \tag{p1}
> $$

## Conjugation

Let $\mathbf{B}_n$ be any invertible $n \times n$ matrix.
We obtain
$$
\mathbf{I}_n
= \mathbf{B}_n \mathbf{I}_n \mathbf{B}^{-1}_n
= \mathbf{B}_n \mathbf{A}^3_n \mathbf{B}^{-1}_n
= \left( \mathbf{B}_n \mathbf{A}_n \mathbf{B}^{-1}_n \right)^3.
$$

From (A) follows that $\mathbf{A}^\flat_n$ is (not yet) a real matrix.
Let us define
$$
\mathbf{A}^\sharp_n =
\mathbf{B}^\flat_n \mathbf{A}^\flat_n \big( \mathbf{B}^\flat_n \big)^{-1}.
$$

If $\mathbf{A}^\sharp_n$ is a real $n \times n$ matrix, then *at least* we have that BOTH the *trace* $(\chi)$ and the *determinant* $(\Delta)$ are real.
Thus
$$
\chi\big(\mathbf{A}^\sharp_n\big) \in \mathbb{R},\\
\Delta\big(\mathbf{A}^\sharp_n\big) \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
As
$$
\chi\big(\mathbf{P}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{P}^{-1}\big) = \chi(\mathbf{Q}),\\
\Delta\big(\mathbf{P}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{P}^{-1}\big) = \Delta(\mathbf{Q}),
$$
we obtain
$$
p \lambda + q \lambda^2 + r \in \mathbb{R}, \tag 1
$$
$$
\lambda^{p+2q} \in \mathbb{R}. \tag 2
$$
Using (p1) we can write (1) as
$$
(p-q) \lambda + (r-q) \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
As $\lambda \ne \mathbb{R}$, we obtain
$$
p=q. \tag {c1}
$$
And (2) becomes
$$
\lambda^{p+2q} = \lambda^{3p} = 1^p = 1 \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Therefore we obtain

> $$
> \lambda \ne 1,
> p > 0,
> 2p+r = n :
> \mathbf{A}^\flat_n =
> \left[
> \begin{array}{cc}
> \left[
> \begin{array}{cc}
> \lambda & 0 \\
> 0 & \lambda^2
> \end{array}
> \right] \mathbf{I}_p & 0\\
> 0 & \mathbf{I}_r
> \end{array}
> \right]. \tag {A2}
> $$

## Real solution

As
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & \lambda^2
\end{array}
\right]^3 = \mathbf{I}_2,
$$
we can consider the conjugation
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-\frac{1}{2} & \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\mp \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right]^3 = \mathbf{I}_2.
$$
The general solution can be written as

> $$
> p > 0,
> 2p+r = n,
> \mathbf{B}_n \in \mathbb{R}^n,
> \exists \mathbf{B}^{-1}_n \in \mathbb{R}^n:
> $$
>   $$
> \mathbf{A}_n =
> \mathbf{B}_n
> \left[
> \begin{array}{cc}
> \left[
> \begin{array}{cc}
> -\frac{1}{2} & \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
> \mp \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
> \end{array}
> \right] \mathbf{I}_p & 0\\
> 0 & \mathbf{I}_r
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \mathbf{B}^{-1}_n.
> $$

Answer (score 1):

One way you could try this is to note $A^2=A^{-1}$. Then write

$$A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$$

such that $ad+bc=1$. Then,

$$A^2=\pmatrix{a^2+bc&b(a+d)\\c(a+d)&bc+d^2}$$
$$A^{-1}=\pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}$$

Then you see we need things like $a+d=-1$, etc. You could play with these and see if something comes out of it